# How do I turn on / off 'text to fit' in Keynote 9.2

Tags: keynote, text

Driving me crazy - Text to fit doesn't show on the presentation I am creating, but does show when I open a apples template slides (under - Inspector - Format - Text - Layout - Under text inset tick box) Is there any way I can disable it on my presentation ?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Shrink Text to Fit" option?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about exactly when and where you are unable to get an option to disable "Shrink text to fit"? One or more screenshots might help as well.